# Surprising properties of closed planar curves

Tags: algebraic-topology, curves, plane-curves

In https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05422 I proved with elementary topological method that a smooth planar curve with total turning number a non-zero integer multiple of $2\pi$ (the tangent fully turns a non-zero number of times) can always be split into 3 arcs rearrangeable to a closed smooth curve. Here comes one example of what I called the 2-cut theorem.

[image: Example]

I am now writing the introduction to my thesis and I would like to cite more examples of counterintuitive properties of planar closed curves, like the one above I think it is. It came already to my mind the inscribed square problem, asking whether every Jordan curve admits an inscribed square (pic from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275439/jordan-curves-admitting-only-acyclic-inscriptions-of-squares).

[image]

Such a property is still a conjecture for the general case, but proofs have been provided for several special cases and the easier inscribed rectangle problem can be solved with a beautiful topological argument (3Blue1Brown made a very nice video about that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8&t=169s).

My question: **what are other surprising properties of closed planar curves you are aware of?**

Comment: Just a short comment on your (nice) paper. I don’t understand your definition of winding number. The point $(1,0)$ can have any of the polar coordinates $(1,2\pi k),k\in \Bbb Z$ isn’t it? So just by comparing $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ I don’t see how you can find out if the curve did in fact turn...

Comment: @PrudiiArca, nice you looked into the paper :) You are right when you say that $(1,0)$ can be written in several ways when it comes to polar coordinates and the same is true for curves parametrized like that. Nevertheless, one can require that the angle function $\phi$ is continuous so, after picking the initial value, all the others are uniquely determined. This makes at least the difference $\phi(b)-\phi(a)$ well defined.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363495/surprising-properties-of-closed-planar-curves